# Website not working on any mobile browser except Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I'm working on a 2048 clone and everything works perfectly. I've deployed to netlify and it works on a desktop browser but will not work on any android browser except for Chrome. I thought it was a netlify issue, so I pushed it to Github pages but got the same issue there.

I tried bundling all files with webpack, thinking it was an import issue, but doing that didn't resolve anything. But still I removed all imports and did it the traditional way by adding all scripts to HTML file but that didn't work either. I added -webpack and -moz properties to the CSS but to no avail.

I also changed all my arrow functions to normal function syntax, but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code for the website
https://github.com/Johan-Liebert1/2048clone

Comment: I accessed the [GitHub](https://Johan-Liebert1.github.io/2048clone/index.html) version of your webpage using Firefox and the Samsung browser on my Android phone and the game seems to play. If I swipe the game grid, the images move and change. As a second check, I uploaded your page to my server and it works from there as well. I did try to use the page with the Firefox touch emulation on my laptop, but that didn’t work (the Firefox touch emulation doesn’t seem to work, but Chrome does).

Comment: Now, for some reason it works on android Firefox and iOS safari but doesn't work on android edge browser. Any idea what could've caused this? I even updated all the browsers but it still didn't work.

Comment: You do have a strange problem. All of my webpages work on all devices. A few other thoughts (but by no means a solution) are to add a version to your JavaScript files (src="js/tile.js?v=001") as at least Android will always use the cached file, add a temporary alert message to find out what is and what isn’t working, and maybe consider using pointer events rather than touch (that’s a long shot).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement them in code